# Python FTP server with dynamically created file

Tags: python, ftp

I have a script that dynamically creates files based on different input (autoconf.py), file name beeing one of it.

I would like to create an ftp server that takes the requested file name, starts the autoconf.py script (which creates the file) and then presents the file to the user.

I found the following implementation (using twisted), but I can't find how to do the dynamical part:

```
from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPFactory, FTPRealm
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import AllowAnonymousAccess, FilePasswordDB
from twisted.internet import reactor

p = Portal(FTPRealm('./'),
           [AllowAnonymousAccess(), FilePasswordDB("pass.dat")])

f = FTPFactory(p)

reactor.listenTCP(21, f)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but I suspect you should override the BuildProtocol method, to modify the ftp factory in order to catch the file not found handling.